# Why does Key Listener only sometimes work

Tags: java, actionlistener, keylistener

So here's my code. I implemented keyListener and actionListener.  I was able to change the coordinates for the panel so It could be able to move left or right. But I have noticed that keyListener doesn't focus very well. I Have to close and rerun the app again and again for it to work and I am able to control it.  I have heard of keyBidings but I don't really get it as much. How can I implement keyBindings to make the keyboard responses more focusable?

```
 package brickBreaker;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.Timer;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class game extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener {
    private Timer timer;
    private boolean play = false;
    private int playerx = 650;
    private int ballx=900, bally=500,ballxdir=-1,ballydir=-2;
    int delay =8;
    public game() {
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        timer = new Timer(delay, this);
        timer.start();

    }


    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(1, 1, 1500 ,950);

        // user panel
        g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        g.fillRect(playerx, 900, 250, 15);

        //ball
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillOval(ballx, bally, 30, 30);

        g.dispose();
    }



    public void right() {
        play = true;
        playerx += 20;
    }
    public void left() {
        play = true;
        playerx -=20;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if(key ==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            System.out.print("Left\n");
            left();
        }if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            System.out.print("Right\n");
            right();
        }



    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {


    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        timer.start();
        if (play) {

            ballx +=ballxdir;
            bally +=ballydir;
            if (ballx <0) {
                ballxdir =-ballxdir;
            }
            if (bally <0) {
                ballydir =-ballydir;
            }
            if (ballx <1000) {
                ballxdir =-ballxdir;
            }




        }
        repaint();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for being *extremely* late to answer, but I think I've fixed your problem.

You're right - You need to open and close the JPanel again and again before it works. But the issue is this: The JPanel keeps losing focus. So all you have to do is add:

```
requestFocus(true);
```

to the `paint()` method, like so:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    requestFocus(true);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(1, 1, 1500 ,950);

    // user panel
    g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    g.fillRect(playerx, 900, 250, 15);

    //ball
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillOval(ballx, bally, 30, 30);

    g.dispose();
}
```

and the program works!

Comment: So simple... so elegant.  Thank you.